# The connection has timed out

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET page that can take anywhere from a couple of seconds to a couple of hours to run depending on the reporting being requested.

The page has worked fine for some time but recently we've started receiving "The connection has timed out" error after exactly five minutes.

I created a simple test page with the below code and likewise it is timing out after five minutes

As you can see the page should pause for six minutes and then display "It worked".

The issue happens when I test locally and on our remote staging server but not on the production server.

I can't see any obvious differences between the website set-up on the staging server compared to the production server.

```
Partial Class Time
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(600000)

        Response.Write("It worked")

    End Sub

End Class
```

In the web.config I have the following settings which should allow a page 10 minutes to process

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0">
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="600"></httpRuntime>
```

Comment: is this exception coming from the Database that you maybe accessing?? have you tried to use profiler to see where the problem is in your application? Are you even sure the problem is in your application and not a change in infrastructure somewhere?

Comment: As you can see I'm not trying to access any database in the test page. I can't rule out infrastructure change but it's strange that it happens both on my local PC and the staging server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stumbled upon the answer and it turns out it's nothing to do with a code setting or server configuration.

Instead it's the browser that is raising the "connection timed out" event.

I was testing in Firefox which gives the above error after five minutes but the code runs to completion okay when using Internet Explorer or Google Chrome.